# #11 versus 6th in musical notation

Tags: chords, notation

I am a new guy here--having a hard time with this any help will be much appreciated--I have seen a chord described as Abmaj7/add 6 versus Abmaj7 #11  are they the same but written differently? Many thanks

Comment: Are you sure it was Abmaj7#11, not just Ab7#11?

Answer (score 2):

Not quite! The ♯11 is enharmonically equivalent to the ♯4 or ♭5, whereas the 6th is equivalent to the 13th. For an A♭ chord, the 6th is an F, whereas the ♯11 is a D♮.

Perhaps you could quote directly from a source so we can identify the exact source of confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The chord of A♭maj7 contains the notes A♭, C, E♭ and G. Both of the quoted chords will have those.

**Add 6**: the major 6th note of A♭ is F, so add that into the mix and we have A♭ maj7 (add6).

**♯11**: the 11th of A♭ is D♭, so when sharpened will become D♮. Put that into the original mix, and we have A♭maj7♯11.

Two slightly different mixes, making two slightly different sounding chords.

Answer (score 0):

11 and 6 are not the same. The pairs of "the same" notes are:

- 2 = 9
- 4 = 11
- 6 = 13

But that's **not** all there is to it.

Even though they "sound" the same, they are used in different contexts. In a dominant chord, you will usually find 9, 11 and 13. In a major chord, you will see 6 and 2 (4 is not used alone, it's only seen in "sus4").

Since the only difference between a major chord and a dominant chord is in the 7th (major 7 in a major chord, minor 7 in a dominant chord), when you see just the 9, 11 or 13, the minor seventh is implied. So, even though 6 and 13 are the same:

- C6 is C E G A
- C13 is C E G **Bb** A